# This is the query I am trying to run in neo4j but it takes too long to run:

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher, time-complexity, graph-databases

I am trying to run this query using Neo4j but it takes too long (more than 30 min, for almost 2500 nodes and 1.8 million relationships) to run:

```
Match (a:Art)-[r1]->(b:Art)  
with collect({start:a.url,end:b.url,score:r1.ed_sc}) as row1

MATCH (a:Art)-[r1]->(b:Art)-[r2]->(c:Art)

Where a.url<>c.url
with row1 + collect({start:a.url,end:c.url,score:r1.ed_sc*r2.ed_sc}) as row2

Match (a:Art)-[r1]->(b:Art)-[r2]->(c:Art)-[r3]->(d:Art)

WHERE a.url<>c.url and b.url<>d.url and a.url<>d.url


with row2+collect({start:a.url,end:d.url,score:r1.ed_sc*r2.ed_sc*r3.ed_sc}) as allRows

unwind allRows as row

RETURN row.start as start ,row.end as end , sum(row.score) as final_score limit 10;
```

Here `:Art` is the label under which there are 2500 nodes, and there are bidirectional relationships between these nodes which has a property called `ed_sc`. So basically I am trying to find the score between two nodes by traversing one, two and three degree paths, and then sum these scores.

Is there a more optimized way to do this?

Comment: Is `url` unique between :Art nodes? If so then you can do your comparisons on the nodes themselves rather than their properties: `WHERE a <> c` which should save you some time.

Comment: I tried this, but didnt get any significant result.

Answer (score 0):

For one I'd discourage use of bidirectional relationships. If your graph is densely connected, this kind of modeling will play havoc on most queries like this.

Assuming `url` is unique for each :Art node, it would be better to compare the nodes themselves rather than their properties.

We should also be able to use variable-length relationships in place of your current approach:

```
MATCH p = (start:Art)-[*..3]->(end:Art)  
WHERE all(node in nodes(p) WHERE single(t in nodes(p) where node = t))
WITH start, end, reduce(score = 1, rel in relationships(p) | score * rel.ed_sc) as score
WITH start, end, sum(score) as final_score
LIMIT 10
RETURN start.url as start, end.url as end, final_score
```

Comment: The above code gives the following error:         single(...) requires a WHERE predicate (line 3, column 34 (offset: 85))
"WHERE all(node in nodes(p) WHERE single(node in nodes(p)))"

Comment: Also I am a newbie in Neo4j so can u plz explain what is the purpose of the second line in your code.

Comment: I read the documentation and found that single requires a 'where' predicate ,what should that statement be in my case.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated. The idea on the second line is to ensure none of the nodes in each path are duplicated. The restriction is that for each node in the path, that the node only appears once in the path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however now it shows a different error "key not found : r ".   I guess there is still some issue with the second line .

Comment: Variables on var-length relationships were deprecated, forgot about that. I removed the `r` variable from the query